# PSexec copyright output

Tags: powershell, psexec, sysinternals

Does anyone know, how to disable "copyright header" from appearing when running PSExec? Everutime I run "./psexec ..." command I see this message:

```
PsExec v2.11 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2014 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com
```

It's really annoying and it bloats up output of my script.

Thanks 
Matthew

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There does not appear to be a way to disable it from occurring, but as a workaround you could redirect STDERR which will suppress the output,

```
psexec \\remotemachine command 2>nul
```

Answer (score 24):

PsExec v2.2 comes with `-nobanner` option.

Answer (score 3):

Or better you can do

```
set F1=find /v "PsExec v2.11 - Execute processes remotely"
set F2=find /v "Copyright (C) 2001-2014 Mark Russinovich"
set F3=find /v "Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com"
set FILTER=%F1%^|%F2%^|%F3%

psexec \\remotemachine command 2>&1 | %FILTER%
```

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a rather old question, but since it's tagged `PowerShell` and there hasn't been a `PowerShell` specific response, here goes:

I wanted to get the value of the environment variable `%SystemRoot%` on a remote machine, without enabling `WinRM`.
My invocation in `PowerShell` was:
`$ret = & PsExec.exe \\RemoteMachine powershell.exe -Command '$env:SYSTEMROOT'`

This returned an array of type `Object[]`, with one element per line of output received.
Sample output, with corresponding array index:

```
PS> $ret
(0)
(1) PsExec v2.2 - Execute processes remotely
(2) Copyright (C) 2001-2016 Mark Russinovich
(3) Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com
(4)
(5) C:\WINDOWS
```

As you can see my desired output was the 6th value in the returned array.

This does also work with `PowerShell` scripts or commands that output more than one line, as each printed line is appended to the array as a new element.

With that in mind we can tidy our returned output up with the following:
`$ret = $ret[5..($ret.Count - 1)]`

This basically just removes the first five elements.

I have not tested this solution with programs other than `PowerShell` though, so use with care.

Comment: you sir, saved me some serious time and head scratching on this one. ta!

Answer (score 2):

Did you try this:

```
psexec.exe -nobanner -accepteula
```

Answer (score 0):

Its work for me:

`(.\PsExec.exe -h \\$Server powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -NoProfile -NonInteractive -NoLogo -File "C:\$WorkFolder\$File") | Findstr /v "Sysinternals" | Findstr /v "PsExec" | Findstr /v "Russinovich"`